# Analyzing pcap data manually in Python

Tags: python

I would like to ask about proccess of formating raw data from pcap file.
Ive got code like this that in my opinion ,if i understand it reads pcap file.

```
import dpkt

f = open('eth-1.pcap', "rb")
pcap = dpkt.pcap.Reader(f)

for ts in pcap:
    print(ts)
```

and i get this on the output:
[image]

I would like to ask what kind of format is this, because my goal is to manually format pcap file packets to readable format and get informations from that like procotols, source ip, destination ip etc.

Something like this:

[image]

**But I cannot USE commands to do it from libraries, but just manually from input.**

I there some documents that i can get some info about how to do it from format like this?

**Or even get data in some another format but please not in already formated.**

THANKS

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text. Post the text itself, formatted as a code sample. That makes it easier to read, easier to work with, and keeps your question from becoming confusing because the image links have expired.

Comment: It looks like you're already using the `dpkt` library to parse the pcap file. Can't you just use the methods provided by that library to further process the pcap data? FWIW, the output that you're showing in the first example is a timestamp followed by the raw ethernet frame data.

Comment: @larsks i know it would be great to use commands to do it but i got it in school that i have to do it manually, so im looking for some manual how to read that raw data ? thanks

Comment: Well, Wikipedia has some information on the [structure of an ethernet frame](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame). Many books or online resources about networking will have the information you need.